# How to avoid a skype block by internet provider

Tags: ip, skype, blocking, voip, provider

Maybe this question could look a bit dodgy: I'm in the need of using Skype for an online meeting.

However I've discovered that starting from this year my IP won't allow Skype connections anymore (same for p2p).

I solved this by using other VOIP services but when it comes to work I have many clients who use skype and it's annoying/unprofessional to ask them to install another software etc.

Do you think there is a way to avoid this block?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Skype hasn't used P2P traffic in several years.  The best way to avoid a block like this is to use a VPN.  Be sure this does not violate your country's laws

Comment: can I use a free VPN service for this purpouse?

Comment: There is nothing "free" in life there is always a cost.  A free VPN would mean the amount of traffic between you and the VPN would be heavly restricted.  In other words you will get what you paid for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can spare some money I would suggest buying a VPS somewhere where skype is not blocked (i.e. Linode VPS in London) and then if you are linux user just ssl-tunnel into your VPS and run skype through that tunnel. You can tunnel through known port (i.e. 80) so this should pass uncovered through internet provider.

And nice thing about VPS - you can build much more on it, your own mail server, http server, e-robot, whatever you need.